# Trouble with simple in-line code (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why do the two statements below result in a different outcome? What am I missing here?

```
list = [1,2]

if (item < 0 for item in list):
    print "This prints."  

for item in list:
    if item < 0:
        print "This doesn't print."
```

Comment: `if (item < 0 for item in list):` statement has no sense. Probably you wanted something like `if any(item < 0 for item in list):`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is a generator expression, and the truthiness will be determined by whether or not any items are produced. *It will either print exactly once or zero times*. In this sense, you would get the same behavior for any length list.

The second actually iterates over each item, and will print *for each item that satisfies that condition*.

A (hacky) workaround to make this a one-liner would be

```
>>> l = [-1, -2, 1, 2]
>>> print('this prints\n' * len([item for item in l if item < 0]))
this prints
this prints
```

Comment: Ah thanks generators have always confused me. Is there anyway to change the generator expression to do what the other does (but in one line)?

Comment: @ElConfuso You can reduce your loop to the following one line: `for item in (item for item in list if item < 0): print "This doesn't print."`

Answer (score 0):

Your first if is a generator expression. It will always be True because it is not `None`:

```
alist = [1,2]

if (item < 0 for item in alist):
    print 'always be True'
    print (item < 0 for item in alist)

print (item < 0 for item in alist).next()
print [i for i in (item < 0 for item in alist)]
```

Your second code is ok for the logic.

Note: do not use list as a variable name.